# como hacer aleatorio un array de strings?

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

Tengo un array y quiero hacer aleatorio este array para que cada vez que inicie la app los elementos esten en una posicion diferente, como puedo hacer esto? he encontrado diferentes extensiones en internet, y algunas funcionan, pero al hacerlo aleatorio, repiten algunas piezas y pues no me sirve o no funcionan por que me sale este error

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[String]'

He buscado como resolver este error, pero lo que encuentro no logro entender el por que del error o como solucionarlo, soy un principiante en swift, apenas estoy trabajando con Spritekit, pensé que el error era por que el array está en una struct, y la cambié a una clase pero no funcionó, estoy usando swift 4.1 espero alguien me pudiera orientar en como solucionar esta sitación les agradezco desde ya :)

**EDIT**
He encontrado el error del por que me repite elementos, ese array y propiedades las tengo en otra clase/struct y necesito acomodar los elementos de cierta manera una vez que los acomodo, los agrego a la escena con un for y ese for, creo manda a llamar la clase 25 veces entonces por eso me repite los elementos, espero poder haberme explicado y pues ojala ahora si me puedan ayudar :(

```
 for container in 0...24{

            self.addChild(containerSprite[container].block)

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

la solución sería:

```
  var names = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"];

  for index in names.indices {
   let number = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count))
   names.swapAt(index.hashValue, Int(number))
  }
```

Para iOS 12, o xcode 10, saldrá una nueva función llamada shuffle(), que hará un random a los arrays, te dejo el link. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle

O sea solo sería

```
var names = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"];
names.shuffle()
```

Comment: Una disculpa he encontrado mi error ya edite mi pregunta, no se si pudieras aun ayudarme, gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución que te propongo es la siguiente:

1. Creas un array que inicialmente esta vacío.
2. Obtienes el numero de elementos que tiene el array con todos los Strings (array.count)
3. Haces un bucle hasta que ese numero de elementos sea 0, y en cada iteración del bucle:

   - Generas un numero aleatorio entre 0 y el numero de elementos -1
   - Sacas del array con los Strings el elementos sacado, lo insertas en el array vacío y lo eliminas del del inicial.
   - Restas uno al numero de elementos que se encuentran en el array inicial.

Siento no poder enviarte el código, de cualquier manera, la solucion es lo que importa :)

Comment: Una disculpa he encontrado mi error ya edite mi pregunta, no se si pudieras aun ayudarme, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser:

```
func randomArray() {
    var randomValues: [String] = [String]()
    var copyContainers = containers

    for _ in 0..<containers.count {
        let random = copyContainers.randomElement()
        randomValues.append(random)
        copyContainers = copyContainers.filter{$0 != random}
    }

    print(randomValues)
}

extension Array {
    func randomElement() -> Element  {
        return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))]
    }
}
```

Comment: Una disculpa he encontrado mi error ya edite mi pregunta, no se si pudieras aun ayudarme, gracias